# Does ML.NET accepts null?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, .net-core, ml.net, machine-learning-model

I'm new for Machine Learning. I'm trying to predict a winner from a race. For this, I'm using the last 5 form of a runner. But some runners don't have 5 form. The dataset is CSV a file. The format similar below.

```
RaceID, BP, Dist, L1FP, L1Marg, L2FP, L2Marg, L3FP, L3Marg, L4FP, L4Marg, L5FP, L5Marg, FP
10      1,  1000, 1,    3.1,    1,    2.5,    2,    2.8,    3,    3.2,    1,    2.8,    1
10      2,  1000, 2,    4.1,    2,    3.5,    2,    4.1,    NULL, NULL,   NULL, NULL,   3
10      3,  1000, 2,    5.3,    3,    3.2,    3,    3.5,    4,    4.9,    NULL, NULL,   2
11.......................................................................................
11......................................................................................
```

I would like to rank the runners using the FP. In here all 3 runners didn't have last 5 form. Runner 2 had last 3 form. runner 3 had last 4 form. Does ML.NET allow `nullable`?

I'm planning to use Ranking as the task as this example:
https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/Ranking_Web

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to fill in the null values.

You can do it in ML.NET by [indicating missing values](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/samples/Microsoft.ML.Samples/Dynamic/Transforms/IndicateMissingValues.cs) and then [replacing those missing values](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/samples/Microsoft.ML.Samples/Dynamic/Transforms/ReplaceMissingValues.cs). If there's not a lot of rows that have missing values, then it can be easier to just drop those rows, but be mindful that you are removing data for the machine learning algorithm to use.

If it helps, I also have a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w67dNSulQTE) that goes over the above, as well, but the sample code for those are linked above.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you Jon. Liked and subscribed. I will check your whole ML.NET playlist. 
If you don't mind can I request you to add a tutorial for ML.NET Ranking task too? I'm very new to ML.NET and Machine Learning.